# How to dynamically select the option for dynamically added select/option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

HTML code:

```
<table id="test">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>col1</th>
             <th>col2</th>
             <th>col3 </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="test1">
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Javascript:

```
    function addData() {
      $.get('ServletCall', {}, function(Servresponse) {
        $.each(Servresponse, function(key, val) {
          var row = "<tr>";
          row += "<td>" + val.col1 + "</td>";
          row += "<td>" + val.col2 + "</td>";
          row += "<td>" +
            "<select id='dropdown'>\n\
                                    <option value='num1'>1</option>\n\
                                    <option value='num2'>2</option>\n\
                                    <option value='num3'>3</option>\n\
                            </select>" + "</td>";
          row += "</tr>";
          $("#test1").append(row);
          $('#dropdown', row).val(val.number).prop("selected", true);
        });
      });
    }
```

This line is not working:

```
$('#dropdown',row).val(val.number).prop("selected", true) ;
```

It always displays the option #1 by default

Example:

- In row1 - I want to have option#1 to be selected by default
- In row2 - I want to have option#3 selected by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s must be unique, but apart from that - you're searching within the HTML text *after* appending it to the document. Nothing you do to the text will have any effect at that point.

Get a jQuery object first, and search within *that*:

```js
val = {
  number: 'num2',
  col1: "col 1",
  col2: "col 2"
};

var row = "<tr>";
row += "<td>" + val.col1 + "</td>";
row += "<td>" + val.col2 + "</td>";
row += "<td>" +
  "<select class='dropdown'>\n\
                                <option value='num1'>1</option>\n\
                                <option value='num2'>2</option>\n\
                                <option value='num3'>3</option>\n\
                        </select>" + "</td>";
row += "</tr>";
var jrow = $(row).appendTo($('#test1'));

jrow.find('.dropdown').val(val.number);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=test1>
</div>
```

Note that setting `val()` on the `<select>` element takes care of `selected` on the `<option>`. No need to do anything further.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me with generating the unique ids.